# Comparing a prefix tree against a HashSet of strings in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, comparative-review, tree, trie

Here, I have made an attempt to find out whether a [prefix tree](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) is any more efficient than a simple `java.util.HashSet<String>`. See what I have:

**`com.github.coderodde.text.autocomplete.PrefixTree.java`:**

```
package com.github.coderodde.text.autocomplete;

import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.ConcurrentModificationException;
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Queue;

/**
 * This class implements a prefix tree (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Jan 19, 2022)
 * @since 1.6 (Jan 19, 2022)
 */
public class PrefixTree implements Iterable<String> {

    private static final class Node {
        Map<Character, Node> childMap;
        Node parent;
        boolean representsString;
    }
    
    private final Node root = new Node();
    private int size;
    private int modCount;

    public int size() {
        return size;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return size == 0;
    }
    
    public void clear() {
        root.childMap = null;
        size = 0;
        modCount++;
    }
    
    public boolean add(String s) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(s, "The input string is null.");   
        Node node = root;
       
        for (char ch : s.toCharArray()) {
            if (node.childMap == null) {
                node.childMap = new HashMap<>();
            }
            
            if (!node.childMap.containsKey(ch)) {
                Node nextNode = new Node();
                nextNode.parent = node;
                node.childMap.put(ch, nextNode);
                node = nextNode;
            } else {
                // Edge exists. Just traverse it.
                node = node.childMap.get(ch);
            }
        }
        
        if (node.representsString) {
            // The input string is already present in this prefix tree:
            return false;
        }
        
        node.representsString = true;
        size++;
        modCount++;
        return true;
    }
    
    public boolean contains(String s) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(s, "The input string is null.");
        Node node = getPrefixNode(s);
        return node != null && node.representsString;
    }
    
    public boolean remove(String s) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(s, "The input string is null.");
        Node node = getPrefixNode(s);
        
        if (node == null) {
            return false;
        }
        
        if (node.representsString) {
            size--;
            modCount++;
            
            if (node.childMap != null) {
                node.representsString = false;
                return true;
            }
            
            int charIndex = s.length() - 1;
            node = node.parent;
            
            while (node != null) {
                node.childMap.remove(s.charAt(charIndex));
                
                if (node.childMap.isEmpty()) {
                    node.childMap = null;
                }
                
                if (node.representsString) {
                    return true;
                }
                
                charIndex--;
                node = node.parent;
                return true;
            }
            
            return true;
        }
        
        return false;
    }
    
    public List<String> autocomplete(String prefix) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(prefix, "The input string is null.");
        
        Node prefixNodeEnd = getPrefixNode(prefix);
        
        if (prefixNodeEnd == null) {
            return Collections.<String>emptyList();
        }
        
        List<String> autocompleteStrings = new ArrayList<>();
        Queue<Node> nodeQueue = new ArrayDeque<>();
        Queue<StringBuilder> substringQueue = new ArrayDeque<>();
        
        nodeQueue.add(prefixNodeEnd);
        substringQueue.add(new StringBuilder(prefix));
        
        while (!nodeQueue.isEmpty()) {
            Node currentNode = nodeQueue.remove();
            StringBuilder currentStringBuilder = substringQueue.remove();
            
            if (currentNode.representsString) {
                autocompleteStrings.add(currentStringBuilder.toString());
            }
            
            if (currentNode.childMap == null) {
                // No need to expand 'currentNode':
                continue;
            }
            
            for (Map.Entry<Character, Node> entry :
                    currentNode.childMap.entrySet()) {
                
                Node node = entry.getValue();
                StringBuilder stringBuilder =
                        new StringBuilder(currentStringBuilder)
                                .append(entry.getKey());
                
                nodeQueue.add(node);
                substringQueue.add(stringBuilder);
            }
        }
        
        return autocompleteStrings;
    }
    
    @Override
    public Iterator<String> iterator() {
        return new PrefixTreeIterator();
    }
    
    private Node getPrefixNode(String s) {
        Node node = root;
        
        for (int i = 0, len = s.length(); i < len; ++i) {
            if (node == null || node.childMap == null) {
                return null;
            }
            
            node = node.childMap.get(s.charAt(i));
        }
        
        return node;
    }
    
    private final class PrefixTreeIterator implements Iterator<String> {

        private int iterated;
        private final int expectedModCount = PrefixTree.this.modCount;
        private final Deque<Node> nodeDeque = new ArrayDeque<>();
        private final Map<Node, Character> nodeToCharMap = new HashMap<>();
        private final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        
        private PrefixTreeIterator() {
            if (!PrefixTree.this.isEmpty()) {
                nodeDeque.addLast(PrefixTree.this.root);
            }
        }
        
        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return iterated < PrefixTree.this.size;
        }

        @Override
        public String next() {
            checkForComodification();
            
            if (!hasNext()) {
                throw new NoSuchElementException("No more strings to iterate.");
            }
            
            while (true) {
                Node node = nodeDeque.removeFirst();
                
                if (node.representsString) {
                    String string = buildString(node);
                    expand(node);
                    iterated++;
                    return string;
                }
                
                expand(node);
            }
        }
        
        private void expand(Node node) {
            if (node.childMap == null) {
                return;
            }
            
            for (Map.Entry<Character, Node> mapEntry :
                    node.childMap.entrySet()) {
                nodeDeque.addLast(mapEntry.getValue());
                nodeToCharMap.put(mapEntry.getValue(), mapEntry.getKey());
            }
        }
        
        private String buildString(Node node) {
            while (node != null && node != PrefixTree.this.root) {
                char ch = nodeToCharMap.get(node);
                stringBuilder.append(ch);
                node = node.parent;
            }
            
            String string = stringBuilder.reverse().toString();
            stringBuilder.delete(0, stringBuilder.length());
            return string;
        }
    
        private void checkForComodification() {
            if (PrefixTree.this.modCount != expectedModCount) {
                throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.text.autocomplete.AutocompleteSystem.java`:**

```
package com.github.coderodde.text.autocomplete;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * This class implements a simple autocomplete system relying on a 
 * {@link java.util.HashSet} of strings.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Jan 26, 2022)
 * @since 1.6 (Jan 26, 2022)
 */
public class AutocompleteSystem implements Iterable<String> {

    private final Set<String> stringSet = new HashSet<>();
    
    public boolean add(String s) {
        return stringSet.add(s);
    }

    public boolean contains(String s) {
        return stringSet.contains(s);
    }
    
    public boolean remove(String s) {
        return stringSet.remove(s);
    }
    
    public List<String> autocomplete(String prefix) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        
        for (String s : stringSet) {
            if (s.startsWith(prefix)) {
                list.add(s);
            }
        }
        
        return list;
    }
    
    public int size() {
        return stringSet.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<String> iterator() {
        return stringSet.iterator();
    }
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.text.autocomplete.PrefixTreeTest.java`:**

```
package com.github.coderodde.text.autocomplette;

import com.github.coderodde.text.autocomplete.PrefixTree;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertFalse;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class PrefixTreeTest {
    
    private final PrefixTree pt = new PrefixTree();
    
    @Before
    public void before() {
        pt.clear();
    }
    
    @Test
    public void addAndContainsString() {
        assertFalse(pt.contains("in"));
        assertFalse(pt.contains("inn"));
        assertFalse(pt.contains("ink"));
        
        assertTrue(pt.add("in"));
        assertTrue(pt.add("inn"));
        assertTrue(pt.add("ink"));
        
        assertFalse(pt.add("in"));
        assertFalse(pt.add("inn"));
        assertFalse(pt.add("ink"));
        
        assertTrue(pt.contains("in"));
        assertTrue(pt.contains("inn"));
        assertTrue(pt.contains("ink"));
        
        assertTrue(pt.add("ixxxxx"));
        assertTrue(pt.add("ix"));
        
        assertTrue(pt.contains("ixxxxx"));
        assertFalse(pt.contains("ixxxx"));
        assertFalse(pt.contains("ixxx"));
        assertFalse(pt.contains("ixx"));
        assertTrue(pt.contains("ix"));
    }
    
    @Test
    public void remove() {
        assertFalse(pt.remove("aa"));
        pt.add("aa");
        assertTrue(pt.remove("aa"));
        
        pt.add("aaaaa");
        pt.add("aa");
        
        assertTrue(pt.contains("aaaaa"));
        assertTrue(pt.contains("aa"));
        
        assertFalse(pt.remove("a"));
        assertTrue(pt.remove("aa"));
        assertFalse(pt.remove("aaa"));
        assertFalse(pt.remove("aaaa"));
        assertTrue(pt.remove("aaaaa"));
        
        pt.add("aaa");
        assertFalse(pt.remove("aaaaa"));
        
        pt.clear();
        
        pt.add("a");
        pt.add("abbb");
        pt.add("accc");
        
        pt.remove("abb");
        assertFalse(pt.contains("abb"));
        
        pt.remove("abbb");
        assertFalse(pt.contains("abbb"));
    }
    
    @Test
    public void size() {
        assertEquals(0, pt.size());
        
        pt.add("a");
        pt.add("b");
        pt.add("c");
        
        assertEquals(3, pt.size());
        
        pt.remove("b");
        
        assertEquals(2, pt.size());
        
        pt.remove("b");
        
        assertEquals(2, pt.size());
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testAutocomplete() {
        pt.add("aaaa");
        pt.add("bbbb");
        pt.add("bbxs");
        pt.add("bbda");
        
        List<String> strings = pt.autocomplete("bb");
        Collections.<String>sort(strings);
        
        assertEquals(3, strings.size());
        
        assertEquals("bbbb", strings.get(0));
        assertEquals("bbda", strings.get(1));
        assertEquals("bbxs", strings.get(2));
        
        pt.clear();
        pt.add("aaa");
        strings = pt.autocomplete("aaab");
        assertTrue(strings.isEmpty());
    }
    
    @Test
    public void emptyString() {
        pt.add("aa");
        pt.add("ab");
        
        assertFalse(pt.contains(""));
        assertTrue(pt.add(""));
        assertFalse(pt.add(""));
        assertTrue(pt.contains(""));
        
        pt.remove("");
        assertFalse(pt.contains(""));
        
        List<String> list = pt.autocomplete("");
        
        assertEquals(2, list.size());
        Collections.<String>sort(list);
        
        assertEquals("aa", list.get(0));
        assertEquals("ab", list.get(1));
        
        pt.add("");
        
        list = pt.autocomplete("");
        Collections.<String>sort(list);
        
        assertEquals("", list.get(0));
        assertEquals("aa", list.get(1));
        assertEquals("ab", list.get(2));
    }
    
    public void removeBug2() {
        pt.add("");
        pt.add("000");
        pt.add("0");
        pt.add("00");
        
        pt.remove("00");
        List<String> l = pt.autocomplete("");
        assertEquals(3, l.size());
        
        Collections.sort(l);
        
        assertEquals("", l.get(0));
        assertEquals("0", l.get(1));
        assertEquals("000", l.get(2));
    }
    
    @Test
    public void iterator() {
        pt.add("");
        pt.add("0");
        pt.add("00");
        pt.add("01");
        pt.add("000");
        pt.add("0001");
        pt.add("011");
        
        Iterator<String> iter = pt.iterator();
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            list.add(iter.next());
        }
        
        Collections.sort(list);
        
        assertEquals("", list.get(0));
        assertEquals("0", list.get(1));
        assertEquals("00", list.get(2));
        
        assertEquals("000", list.get(3));
        assertEquals("0001", list.get(4));
        assertEquals("01", list.get(5));
        assertEquals("011", list.get(6));
        
    }
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.text.autocomplete.Application.java`:**

```
package com.github.coderodde.text.autocomplete;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

/**
 * This class implements the internal state of the demonstration program for the
 * prefix tree vs. {@link java.util.HashSet}.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Jan 26, 2022)
 * @since 1.6 (Jan 26, 2022)
 */
public class Application {

    private static final class CommandNames {
        static final String ADD_STRING      = "add";
        static final String CONTAINS_STRING = "contains";
        static final String REMOVE_STRING   = "remove";
        static final String AUTOCOMPLETE    = "complete";
        static final String PRINT           = "print";
    }
    
    protected final PrefixTree prefixTree = new PrefixTree();
    
    public void addString(String s) {
        checkInputStringNotNull(s);
        prefixTree.add(s);
        System.out.println(getAllStrings());
    }
    
    public void removeString(String s) {
        checkInputStringNotNull(s);
        prefixTree.remove(s);
        System.out.println(getAllStrings());
    }
    
    public void containsString(String s) {
        checkInputStringNotNull(s);
        System.out.println(prefixTree.contains(s));
    }
    
    public void autocompletePrefix(String prefix) {
        checkPrefixNotNull(prefix);
        List<String> list = prefixTree.autocomplete(prefix);
        Collections.<String>sort(list);
        System.out.println(list);
    }
    
    public void printAll() {
        autocompletePrefix("");
    }
    
    public void processCommand(String[] tokens) {
        switch (tokens.length) {
            case 1:
                processSingleTokenCommand(tokens);
                return;
                
            case 2:
                processDoubleTokenCommand(tokens);
                return;
                
            default:
                String cmd = String.join(" ", tokens);
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Bad command: \"" + cmd + "\"");
        }
    }
    
    private List<String> getAllStrings() {
        List<String> list = prefixTree.autocomplete("");
        Collections.<String>sort(list);
        return list;
    }
    
    private void processSingleTokenCommand(String[] tokens) {
        assert tokens.length == 1;
        
        switch (tokens[0]) {
            case CommandNames.PRINT -> {
                printAll();
                return;
            }
                
            default -> throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Unknown command: " + String.join(" ", tokens));
        }
    }
    
    private void processDoubleTokenCommand(String[] tokens) {
        assert tokens.length == 2;
        
        switch (tokens[0]) {
            case CommandNames.ADD_STRING:
                addString(tokens[1]);
                return;
                
            case CommandNames.AUTOCOMPLETE:
                autocompletePrefix(tokens[1]);
                return;
                
            case CommandNames.CONTAINS_STRING:
                containsString(tokens[1]);
                return;
                
            case CommandNames.REMOVE_STRING:
                removeString(tokens[1]);
                return;
                
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Unknown command: " + String.join(" ", tokens));
        }
    }
    
    private void checkInputStringNotNull(String s) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(s, "The input string is null.");
    }
    
    private void checkPrefixNotNull(String s) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(s, "The prefix is null.");
    }
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.text.autocomplete.Demo`:**

```
package com.github.coderodde.text.autocomplete;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Demo {
    
    private static final int NUMBER_OF_STRINGS_TO_GENERATE = 500_000;
    private static final int MAXIMUM_STRING_LENGTH = 5;
    private static final String AUTOCOMPLETE_STRING = "5";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length > 0 && args[0].trim().equals("benchmark")) {
            benchmark();
        } else {
            runDemo();
        }
    }
    
    private static void runDemo() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Application application = new Application();
        
        while (true) {
            System.out.print(">>> ");
            String commandString = scanner.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase();
            
            if (commandString.equals("quit")) {
                break;
            }
            
            try {
                application.processCommand(commandString.split("\\s+"));
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                System.out.println("ERROR: " + t.getMessage());
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println("Bye!");
    }
    
    private static void benchmark() {
        benchmarkImpl(false);
        benchmarkImpl(true);
    }
    
    private static void benchmarkImpl(boolean printStatistics) {
        if (printStatistics) {
            System.out.println("<<< Benchmarking... >>>");
        }
            
        Random random = new Random(1255L);
        
        String[] strings = getStrings(NUMBER_OF_STRINGS_TO_GENERATE, random);
        String[] queryStrings = getQueryStrings(strings, 4, random);
        shuffle(queryStrings, random);
        
        PrefixTree prefixTree = new PrefixTree();
        AutocompleteSystem autocompleteSystem = new AutocompleteSystem();
        
        long prefixTreeDuration = 0L;
        long autocompletionSystemDuration = 0L;
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        
        for (String s : strings) {
            prefixTree.add(s);
        }
        
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        prefixTreeDuration += end - start;
        
        if (printStatistics) {
            System.out.println("PrefixTree.add() in " + (end - start) + " ms.");
            System.out.println("PrefixTree.size() = " + prefixTree.size());
        }
        
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        
        for (String s : prefixTree) {
            
        }
        
        end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        prefixTreeDuration += end - start;
        
        if (printStatistics) {
            System.out.println("PrefixTree.iterator() in " 
                    + (end - start) + " ms.");
        }
        
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        
        for (String s : queryStrings) {
            prefixTree.contains(s);
        }
        
        end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        prefixTreeDuration += end - start;
        
        if (printStatistics) {
            System.out.println("PrefixTree.contains() in " 
                    + (end - start) 
                    + " ms.");
        }
        
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < queryStrings.length / 2; i += 2) {
            prefixTree.remove(queryStrings[i]);
        }
        
        end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        prefixTreeDuration += end - start;
        
        if (printStatistics) {
            System.out.println("PrefixTree.remove() in " 
                    + (end - start) 
                    + " ms.");
            
            System.out.println("PrefixTree.size() = " + prefixTree.size());
        }
        
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        
        List<String> prefixTreeCompletionStrings = 
                prefixTree.autocomplete(AUTOCOMPLETE_STRING);
        
        end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        prefixTreeDuration += end - start;
        
        Collections.sort(prefixTreeCompletionStrings);
        
        if (printStatistics) {
            System.out.println("PrefixTree.autocomplete() in " + (end - start) + 
                    " ms.");
            
            System.out.println("PrefixTree total duration: " + 
                    prefixTreeDuration + " ms.");
        }
        
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        System.out.println();
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        
        for (String s : strings) {
            autocompleteSystem.add(s);
        }
        
        end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        autocompletionSystemDuration += end - start;
        
        if (printStatistics) {
            System.out.println("AutocompleteSystem.add() in " + (end - start) 
                    + " ms.");
            
            System.out.println("AutocompleteSystem.size() = " + 
                    autocompleteSystem.size());
        }
        
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        
        for (String s : autocompleteSystem) {
            
        }
        
        end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        autocompletionSystemDuration += end - start;
        
        if (printStatistics) {
            System.out.println("AutocompleteSystem.iterator() in " 
                    + (end - start) + " ms.");
        }
        
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        
        for (String s : queryStrings) {
            autocompleteSystem.contains(s);
        }
        
        end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        autocompletionSystemDuration += end - start;
        
        if (printStatistics) {
            System.out.println("AutocompleteSystem.contains() in " 
                    + (end - start) 
                    + " ms.");
        }
        
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < queryStrings.length / 2; i += 2) {
            autocompleteSystem.remove(queryStrings[i]);
        }
        
        end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        autocompletionSystemDuration += end - start;
        
        if (printStatistics) {
            System.out.println("AutocompleteSystem.remove() in " 
                    + (end - start) 
                    + " ms.");
            
            System.out.println("AutocompleteSystem.size() = " + 
                    autocompleteSystem.size());
        }
        
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        
        List<String> autocompleteSystemCompletionStrings = 
                autocompleteSystem.autocomplete(AUTOCOMPLETE_STRING);
        
        end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        autocompletionSystemDuration += end - start;
        
        Collections.sort(autocompleteSystemCompletionStrings);
        
        if (printStatistics) {
            System.out.println("AutocompleteSystem.autocomplete() in " 
                    + (end - start) + " ms.");
            
            System.out.println("AutocompleteSystem total duration: " + 
                    autocompletionSystemDuration + " ms.");
            
            System.out.println();
            
            System.out.println("Data structures agree: " + 
                    prefixTreeCompletionStrings
                            .equals(autocompleteSystemCompletionStrings));
            
            System.out.println("PrefixTree returned " + 
                    prefixTreeCompletionStrings.size() + " strings.");
            
            System.out.println("AutocompleteSystem returned " +
                    autocompleteSystemCompletionStrings.size() + " strings.");
        }
    }
    
    private static String[] getQueryStrings(String[] strings, Random random) {
        return getQueryStrings(strings, MAXIMUM_STRING_LENGTH, random);
    }
    
    private static String[] getQueryStrings(String[] strings, 
                                            int maximumStringLength, 
                                            Random random) {
        
        String[] queryStrings = new String[strings.length];
        int index = 0;
        
        for (; index < strings.length / 2; ++index) {
            queryStrings[index] = strings[index];
        }
        
        for (; index < strings.length; ++index) {
            queryStrings[index] = generateString(maximumStringLength, random);
        }
        
        return queryStrings;
    }
    
    private static String[] 
        getStrings(int numberOfStringsRandom, Random random) {
        return getStrings(numberOfStringsRandom, MAXIMUM_STRING_LENGTH, random);
    }
    
    private static String[] 
        getStrings(int numberOfStringsRandom, 
                   int maximumStringLength, 
                   Random random) {
            
        String[] strings = new String[numberOfStringsRandom];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; ++i) {
            strings[i] = generateString(maximumStringLength, random);
        }
        
        return strings;
    }
    
    private static String generateString(int maximumStringLength, 
                                         Random random) {
        int stringLength = random.nextInt(maximumStringLength + 1);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(stringLength);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < stringLength; ++i) {
            sb.append('0' + (char)(random.nextInt(10)));
        }
        
        return sb.toString();
    }
    
    private static void shuffle(String[] arr, Random random) {
        for (int i = arr.length - 1; i > 0; --i) {
            int j = random.nextInt(i);
            String s = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = s;
        }
    }
}
```

The output on my PC is:

```
<<< Benchmarking... >>>
PrefixTree.add() in 62 ms.
PrefixTree.size() = 67741
PrefixTree.iterator() in 52 ms.
PrefixTree.contains() in 92 ms.
PrefixTree.remove() in 18 ms.
PrefixTree.size() = 47652
PrefixTree.autocomplete() in 15 ms.
PrefixTree total duration: 239 ms.

AutocompleteSystem.add() in 37 ms.
AutocompleteSystem.size() = 67741
AutocompleteSystem.iterator() in 4 ms.
AutocompleteSystem.contains() in 52 ms.
AutocompleteSystem.remove() in 7 ms.
AutocompleteSystem.size() = 47652
AutocompleteSystem.autocomplete() in 4 ms.
AutocompleteSystem total duration: 104 ms.

Data structures agree: true
PrefixTree returned 38122 strings.
AutocompleteSystem returned 38122 strings.
```

So, no, prefix tree can't beat the `HashSet<String>`.

**Critique request**

I am eager to hear all the improvement comments that might come to mind.

Comment: For *one* Set.get(key) you use *key.length() times* Map.get(c).
I think Map.get() and Set.get() share the same code base.

Comment: Since the purpose is performance optimization, it would seem sensible to use an `IntMap<Node>` instead of `Map<Character, Node>`.

Comment: Have you used a profiler? Showing you where most of the time is spent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking a single sample and calculating it's duration from the wall clock is an extremely error prone method to compere execution speed. A single OS interrupt and the measured time no longer means anything. to improve the accuracy, you can run the code several times and generate statistics to reduce possibility of outside effects causing errors.

You need to change the `AutocompleteSystem` into an interface and create `PrefixTreeAutocomplete` and `HashMapAutoComplete` and a single test suite without copy-paste code, that can run the same test against any `AutocompleteSystem` implementation it receives.

Performance wise, hash table's advantages are pretty obvious. This is a well known fact and it's documented in the side bar of the wikipedia article you linked. :) Prefix trees have a storage space advantage when you have a lot of identical string prefixes, but you're giving a bit of that advantage away by using regular HashMaps internally. Each character now consumes a 32bit integer as the array index, a 32bit pointer to the `Character`-key within `Map.Entry` and whatever the Map.Entry and Character objects themselves take.

I assume the operation that is most important for the regular use case is the `autocomplete(String)` method. The prefix tree has an awful hadicap because it has to recreate the strings every time it is needed. To get an advantage over a HashMap, you could trade some of the storage space advantage into performance by adding the completed string into the `Node` as `completeString` and removing the now redundant `representsString` field. Then you can just return the existing string instead of building it character by character with a `StringBuilder` (clone the String before storing it so you don't leak memory by holding on to substrings from longer documents).